# VS2015 Error List items all doubled

Tags: visual-studio-2015

In VS2015, I'm working on native C++ if that matters, all the warnings in the Error List are doubled.  I know headers will be included multiple times, but I can see that an item for a .cpp file is listed twice with the same line number and identical contents.

I've disabled any extensions I can, and the filter option is set for "Build Only" (not also showing Intellisence errors).  (The only thing I found on web searches was for different kinds of projects where different tools were both finding the error)

I don't know where else to look for what's causing it.

[image]

I've redacted the project names and file names, but each item in the pair is identical in these fields as well.  The bottom pair is from a Qt `*.ui` code generator, not the CL task.  This tells me that it's not an individual Task causing this, but something about the Error List as a whole.

They are not doubled in the Output window.  This occurs even just after loading the project and building, so there is nothing leftover in the Error List memory from a previous compile.

Comment: have you tried cleaning? (assuming the option exists for C++)

Comment: Yes; after a Clean, after quitting and restarting DevEnv.  They always show two for each one in the Output window.

Comment: Can you reproduce the same behaviour, if you create a new "Hello World" project from the "Visual C++" -> "Empty Project" template? Is your project using WPF, XAML or .Net?

Comment: Are you compiling it to "Any CPU", or to your specific platform (x86, x64...)?

Comment: The project is Specific to x86. Only "win32" is available as an option, @anolsi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First try if you can reproduce this behavior with an minimal C++ example (plain commandline application without Qt). Create a new project from `"File" -> "New" -> "Project" -> "Visual C++" -> "Empty Project"` and add only one C++ file as new item. i.e.

```
int main() {
  long a = 1;
  float b = a;
}
```

If your problem still persists try to reset your Visual-Studio Settings: To do this select from the Menubar `"Tools" -> "Import and Export Settings Wizard" -> "Reset all settings" -> "No, just reset settings, overwriting my current settings"`. After doing this & performing a full rebuild, it should not list any error/warning twice anymore (except for the case, that you have the same error/warning really occurring twice in the affected lines - but I doubt, this is the case for you). It's possible that either from an update or by accidently changing some settings, Visual studio was performing two stages of compilation - in this case all errors & warnings are listed two times too: i.e. when building a WPF application that uses a XAML file this is the case.

Comment: The "minimal project" also shows the warning doubled.

Comment: @JDługosz Did you tried resetting the settings and are warnings still doubled?

Comment: after resetting as indicated, the problem seems to be solved!  I'd still like to understand better why it was doing that.  I do recall it seemed to happen after it installed an update.  I'll work with the project normally and make sure it's really fixed.  :)

Comment: Losing all your settings isn't fun. I'd actually put up with duplicate messages just to avoid losing all my settings.

Answer (score 5):

In my experience, this issue is caused by setting MSBuild verbosity to Normal instead of Minimal. So the simplest, least destructive, fix is: Tools...Options...Projects and Solutions...Build and Run...MSBuild project build output verbosity: Minimal.

Answer (score 2):

One possibility is that you are looking at the Error List Window with the window configured to show both Build and Intellisense errors.

If that's the case, look for a drop-down box to the right of the Errors, Warnings and Messages buttons.  The box will say "Build+Intellisense".  Change it to "Build Only" or "Intellisense Only" as desired.

[image]

Comment: I already noted this was not the case in the OP.  *"..., and it's set for "Build Only" (not also showing Intellisence errors)"*

Comment: Sorry, I misinterpreted what "it" was.  It might help if you posted a screenshot of your Error List window.

Comment: I'll do that tomorrow.  But I'll describe it: each item is twice, *identical*, unlike your screen shot which shows different icons and descriptions.